# Is it necessary to add Tile layer background?

Tags: web-mapping, geojson, leaflet

Is it necessary to add tile layer for making a `GeoJSON` data rendered in web browser using Leaflet or any other API ?

I have a geoJSON data (I obtained the GeoJSON data by converting `.shp` file to GeoJSON using `ogr2ogr`) of a small hypothetical network which I want to render in the browser. My network when opened in QGIS is shown [image: in this link]

For the above network it makes no sense to add a Tile layer of OSM or any other service. Is there a way I can render the network shown above in the web using leaflet or any other API ?

I'm very new to GIS related thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use a tile layer to display geoJSON features in most APIs. This looks like it does what you want in Leaflet.

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html

One word of warning though. This method will get very slow when you start displaying lots of features- it's then you need to look at using a tile layer for performance reasons.